# Read a mysql properties file using node js

Tags: mysql

I'm new to using MySQL with nodejs so I'm just wondering is there way to read a db.properties file in nodejs like in java's Jdbc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the nodejs [properties-reader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/properties-reader) libary to read a properties file.